# JScrollBar thumb position (value) won't change

Tags: java, swing

I have a JScrollPane `jScrollPane2`. i tried to change the position (value) of the thumb, but its position doesn't change, here's the code :

```
public AfficherArbreSyntaxique() {
        initComponents();

        jPanelPourDessinerArbre1.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(10000, 10000));
        jPanelPourDessinerArbre1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(10000, 10000));
        ;
        //        jPanelPourDessinerArbre1.s //ensureIndexIsVisible
        // jPanelPourDessinerArbre1.repaint();


        jScrollPane2.getVerticalScrollBar().setValueIsAdjusting(true);
        jScrollPane2.getHorizontalScrollBar().getModel().setValue(10);

        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(this.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

    }
```

What is the problem and how to solve it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would guess the GUI is not visible yet so components don't have a size yet.

Try setting the value AFTER the frame is visible. One way to do this is to wrap the code is a SwingUtilities.invokeLater().

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
{
    public void run()
    {
        jScrollPane2.getHorizontalScrollBar().getModel().setValue(10);
    }
});
```